# Olingo v4 + log4j2

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I could not find any information about Olingo v4 system logging like spring boot has.
Tutorial includes slf4j, so there must be internal logging in framework

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But I was not able to find any occurrences of logging configuration in tutorial or sample code.
I want to use log4j2 for logging purposes and I'm expecting specific parameter to be used in web.xml like it works in spring boot

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j2.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Moreover I found ODataDebugCallback implementation for v2 - [Debug Support and Error Handling](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/debug.html)

But it's for v2 and does not work in v4

**Is there any context-param to use or something similar to ODataDebugCallback for logging purposes?**

Small case description.

I have created Olingo v4 OData API above data base. One of it key features is dynamic metadata build. It worked fine initially but when I'm creating new table I'm getting

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": null,
        "message": "OData Library: An exception without message text was thrown."
    }
}
```

And no catch in OData servlet

```
        try {
            /*session, storage, handler, edm providers init here*/

            // let the handler do the work
            handler.process(req, resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Server Error occurred in ODataServlet", e); //app is not getting here
            throw new ServletException(e);
        } finally {
            log.debug("========== Request end ==========");
        }
```

And my log

```
[DEBUG] ODataServlet - ========== Request begin ==========
[DEBUG] ODataServlet - Received GET request /myOdataServer.svc/$metadata from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
[DEBUG] JDBCFactory - Opening connection to jdbc:postgresql://host/card_storage
[DEBUG] ODataServlet - ========== Request end ==========
```

I'm hoping to get more info from framework about error: stack trace, line number, something.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exception trace, You may check the ServerCoreDebugger class.

Basically you need to register DebugSupport to the ODataHttpHandler, and add query parameter like 'odata-debug=json' to your request url to work with the DefaultDebugSupport to get the exception trace from response.

```
handler.register(new DefaultDebugSupport());
```